# Como criar uma cópia da tabela com a data atual no nome no Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Preciso criar uma cópia de uma tabela usando um nome concatenado com a data atual.
Estou usando o seguinte código que não da certo:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_01||NOW() AS
TABLE tbl_01;
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando uma stored procedure, basta criar uma procedure e depois executar esta *stored procedure*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CRIAR_TABELA_DATA_HOJE() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    execute format('create table tbl_xpto%s as table tbl_xpto', to_char(now(), 'DD_MM_YYYY'));
END;
$func$;
```

### Um caso de uso real

Vamos criar uma tabela `usuario` e inserir 4 usuários.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario (
    id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    nome VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO usuario (nome) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO usuario (nome) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO usuario (nome) VALUES ('c');
INSERT INTO usuario (nome) VALUES ('d');
```

Agora queremos criar a nossa *stored_procedure* que vai criar uma nova tabela usuario07_03_2024. A *stored_procedure* deve ser da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CRIAR_TABELA_DATA_HOJE() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
    execute format('create table usuario%s as table usuario', to_char(now(), 'DD_MM_YYYY'));
END;
$func$;
```

Repare que no comando acima, estamos formatando uma data para o formato de string desejado, e o operador possui o mesmo funcionando do formatador de saída no C. Então o resultado será uma data formatada no padrão (DD_MM_YYYY), separada por underline (<kbd>_</kbd>)

Depois para executar a *stored_procedure* basta executar:

```
CALL CRIAR_TABELA_DATA_HOJE()
```

Ao executar o comando deve existir uma nova tabela em seu esquema do banco de dados.

Para verificar, basta rodar o comando `\dt`

```
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------------+-------+----------
 public | usuario           | table | ***
 public | usuario07_03_2024 | table | ***
(2 rows)

=# select * from usuario08_03_2024 ;
                  id                  | nome 
--------------------------------------+------
 2d668121-39b4-4397-ada0-3760f1adccc3 | a
 51f3ec21-61bc-4b42-b7d2-99368b8dd91e | b
 bbbd5aab-db12-4214-a7cc-84149812e94a | c
 6e441abf-dc2e-48c1-a3af-d9cd3a76172f | d
(4 rows)
```

Documentação da função [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

---

### Uma solução utilizando o shell

Uma segunda maneira de resolver o problema é utilizar o shell para "montar" a data e criar a tabela com o resultado de um alias.

Segue um exemplo, de como será o resultado do nome da tabela:

```
echo "tbl_xpto_$(printf '%(%d_%m_%Y)T' -1)"
```

| Formatador | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| %d | dia |
| %m | Mês |
| %Y | (maiúsculo) Ano com 4 dígitos |

A tabela completa dos formatadores pode ser vista na documentação do comando [date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)

Pronto, agora que já sabe como vai ser o nome da tabela, basta utilizar esta mesma lógica para executar este comando utilizando o psql.

Segue um exemplo:

```
psql -U <usuario> <nome-db> -c "CREATE TABLE tbl_xpto_$(printf '%(%d_%m_%Y)T' -1) AS TABLE tbl_01"
```

Repare que no comando acima, estamos passando o parâmetro `-c` e no argumento deste parâmetro passamos o comando DDL que cria a cópia da tabela.

Substitua o valor `<nome-db>` pelo nome do seu banco de dados. Assim como valor do `<usuario>` pelo nome do seu usuário correspondente à sua configuração do banco de dados.

Vale ressaltar também que as regras de formação de nome das tabelas do postgres não é possível ter nomes com `-` (dash), mas se gostaria de utilizar o dash no nome da tabela, pode utilizar a forma de nomes de tabelas literais (onde o nome da tabela deve ser envolvido em aspas duplas). Para saber as regras leia a documentação da sintaxe das [palavras chaves](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Após a execução com sucesso, deve ser solicitado a senha do banco de dados.

Ao final, se tudo ocorrer com sucesso, deve ser exibido a quantidade de linhas contida na tabela.

Como referências para esta resposta utilizei esta [publicação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401495/4598175).

Além da documentação do [Postgres](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-copy-table/)